# Ordenar array de imágenes

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, swift4

Tengo una duda, tengo un array de imágenes y necesito ordenarlo, por el nombre de la imagen, en modo descendente para luego mostrarlo en mi UICollectionView.

Adjunto código a ver si me podéis echar una mano.

```
    var imageArray = [UIImage]()


    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    let documentDirectory = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
    let directoryContents = try! fileManager.contentsOfDirectory(at: documentDirectory, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil)

    for imageURL in directoryContents where imageURL.pathExtension == "jpg" {
        if let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imageURL.path) {

            self.imageArray.append(image)

        }
    }
```

Gracias por todo, saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes optar por crear un objeto `ImageObject` en el que almacenes tanto la imagen como su nombre. Algo así:

```
class ImageObject: NSObject {
    var name: String!
    var image: UIImage!

    init(name: String, image: UIImage) {
        super.init()

        self.name = name
        self.image = image
    }
}
```

Y luego en tu método usarlo de esta forma:

```
var images = [ImageObject]()

let fileManager = FileManager.default
let documentDirectory = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
let directoryContents = try! fileManager.contentsOfDirectory(at: documentDirectory, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil)

for imageURL in directoryContents where imageURL.pathExtension == "jpg"
{
    if let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imageURL.path) {
        let imageObject = ImageObject(name: imageURL.lastPathComponent, image: image)
        images.append(imageObject)
    }
}
```

Y luego ordenas el array de esta forma:

```
images.sort(by: { $0.name < $1.name})
```

Comment: Perfecto, lo haré así. Grácias por tu ayuda